# Search in android activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-search

I am new in android and I am working with a search related feature. After read the tutorial I have some questions:

1 Does the `SearchableActivity` unique in an application?

It seems that 3 steps are required to setup the search feature(from the android developer guide):

1)create the `SearchableActivity` to receive the search keyword.

2)make the `SearchableActivity` to accept the ACTION_SEARCH intent

3)specify the searchable configuration to use, in a  element.

Then I wonder if all the search related job will be delegated to the `SearchableActivity`?

And suppose I have two `MainActivity` and `MainActivityTwo`, both of them make a `SearchView` inside the action bar.

The AndroidMinefset.xml:

```
    <activity android:name="com.app.activity.MainActivityTwo" />
    <activity android:name="com.app.activity.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.app.activity.SearchableActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

xml/search.xml:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</searchable>
```

And register the search configuration(serchableInfo) to`SerchView`:

.MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.u_action_menu_map, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));  
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This does not work, it seems that there is no serchableInfo bound with the current Activity(`MainActivity`).

Even I changed to this:

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName("com.app.activity", "SearchableActivity")));
```

It still cannot find the searchableInfo.

After I add the search related configuration to `MainActivity`:

```
<activity android:name="com.app.activity.MainActivityTwo" />
<activity android:name="com.app.activity.SearchableActivity" />
<activity android:name="com.app.activity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

This worked.  WTF.

I always thought that the Activity provide the Search UI and the Activity handle the input  are different, but after my test it seems that they are the same Activity, that't to say the user input are submit to the Activity itself,but why use the **ing intent to transfer the input data?

2 The search submit

The Search dialog have a search submit button at the right of the dialog:

[image]

But there is nothing inside the `SearchView` so how to submit the search in a `SearchView`:

[image]

Comment: The search button is at the keyboard's bottom right

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `search` key on your keyboard. It can also be `go`, `return` or similar keys that should start the search.

[image]

Comment: I am using HTC e1, there is no `search` key. :(